# How to print ID from the multipurpose tray on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, printing, canon

I have a Canon Pixma Ts704a printer. I'm trying to print ID Cards using the multipurpose tray. But there is no multipurpose tray paper size option on the Page Setup.
How do I print on the MP tray or set the size of the MP tray in the paper size options.

This what the ID tray looks like

[image]

Comment: for printing cards & labels I use gLabels (Ubuntu Software) which allows you to select sizes very simply and effectively (on HP LaserJet) - worth a try?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I couldn't find the tray for Canon Pixma TS704a.. I'm not sure about the sizes of the tray I'd have made a custom

Comment: gLabels relies more on the size of the card rather than the tray specifically... Is it possible to set a printer which just looks for the tray and use that as the printer selection for Labels perhaps? Are the cards mounted on a sheet or individual? Perhaps [edit] that information into your question for clarity

Comment: I have edited the question to include an image of the Tray, do you have any idea what configurations I could use?

Comment: sorry, no. The printer is not familiar to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the gLabels is a lot of help, I'll try to measure everything and set it up manually and hope someone can help with a direct experience.